# Viewing Profile Page of Another Shows Relations of Viewer and Viewee

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

If a registered SE user views another's profile, a possible new feature of `Relations` would be available to the viewer. In the relations section would have these relations to be browsed:

1. **Questions Shared** - where the viewer and viewee both provided an answer to or commented on a post together.
2. **Question Answered** - Shows where the viewer answered a question of the viewee.
3. **Answer Given** - Shows where the viewee answered a question of the viewer's.

Since some super-users could *stack overflow* the results, a limit of 100 could be placed on the sections.

---

While browsing another's profile it struck me I may have answered a question of theirs'. But visually `grep-ping` through their list of questions would have been tedious. In my mind it is a database query and possibly a good feature.

Sometimes one runs into others socially and for the most part the interaction are good. But sometimes knowing the historical interaction, for me atleast, leads to informed decisions on how I should interact with said person when determining whether to vote for a moderator or not.

Comment: In general, the Stack Exchange network is... resistant to adding *"social"* features.

Comment: Can you explain why you would like to see this?

Comment: @CodeCaster added my thoughts why.

Comment: No, that's why you came up with this. :) What benefit would having this functionality have for the user?

Comment: I'm not convinced that answering idle questions like this would be enough of a benefit to be worth the development time and server load.

Comment: @CodeCaster updated for the *why*.

Comment: If you are willing to implement this yourself, a browser plugin connecting to the API would achieve this. Scrape a user ID from the page, send it to a search system, and render the results either in a plugin panel or inject some HTML into a Stack Overflow page.

Comment: I have noticed before that you have a great deal of trouble adjusting to the SO way of doing things.  It is *really* fundamentally different from the forums you used to contribute to.  That's a shame, you were pretty good at it, but that just can't work at SO.  If you want to talk about it then send me an email and I'll try to explain it.

Answer (score 6):

> *"... on how I should interact with said person."*

You don't *interact* with **persons** here primarily (unless you meet them in chat rooms).

Thus showing such comparative statistics would encourage people to keep following particular users. I don't think this would lead to anything good.

Concentrate on content of posts and their quality. That's the most appropriate source you can consider, to improve your own posts.

The actual quality of a posted question or answer doesn't really depend on the reputation of the poster (I'm pretty sure even [@JonSkeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) miserably has been failing about this, and just have been receiving upvotes because of their high-rep). It's a common misconception of people having powers to vote, and they'll may upvote/downvote just by judging reputation of the poster.

---

> *"In order to be an immaculate member of a flock of sheep, one must above all be a sheep oneself."*
>
> <sub>**[Albert Einstein](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins165194.html#WX7WgPsCedvmSFtw.99)**</sub>

Comment: @ryanyuyu _"You don't interact with persons here primarily ..."_ I still prefer this viewpoint, and don't see any need to encourage such with additional comparative statistics shown in a view.

Comment: Ok thanks.  This seems like a good reason to avoid implementing this (rather moot) feature request.